# Custom redirection from checkout to my account and back in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, checkout

There is a site on WordPress and WooCommerce. At the moment, I already have functionality for several conditions when buying products by users:

1. If the user is not registered and he buys any product other than the subscription, he calmly draws up the order and the system automatically creates an account for him. (Done)
2. If the user is registered but forgot to enter under his login, he also quietly draws up an order simply by logging in under his login on the checkout page. (Done)
3. If the user is not registered and wants to buy a subscription, the system redirects it to the registration page, from there to the edit-account page and he goes back to the checkout page. (Done)
4. If the user is registered but forgot to log in with his login, and he wants to buy a subscription. The user redirects to the registration page. He enters login and password. The system redirects back him to the checkout page. (A task)

The first two conditions I created are standard WooCommerce settings. For the third condition, I have code that can be seen:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'woo_custom_redirect');

function woo_custom_redirect($redirect) {
// HERE set your product category (can be term IDs, slugs or names)
$category = 'subscriptions';

$found = false;

// CHECK CART ITEMS: search for items from our product category
foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        if (has_term($category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'])) {
                $found = true;
                break;
        }
}

if (!is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() && $found) {
        wp_redirect('/my-account/edit-account/');                
        exit();
}

if (is_user_logged_in() && !WC()->cart->is_empty() && is_account_page()) {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_checkout_page_id') ) );
}

}
```

For the fourth condition, I added the code:

```
if (is_user_logged_in() &&! WC()->cart->is_empty() && is_account_page ()) {
    wp_redirect (get_permalink (get_option ('woocomm erce_checkout_page_id'))));
}
```

But it does not work as it should. The third condition stops working because of this code.

How can this be remedied? Thanks!

---

**Update:** I save it here. This can help other users. The code is fully working.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_redirections' );
function custom_redirections( $redirect ) {
// HERE set your product category (can be term IDs, slugs or names)
$category = 'subscriptions';

$found = false;

// CHECK CART ITEMS: search for items from our product category
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    if (has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() && $found ) {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) );
    exit();
} elseif ( is_user_logged_in() && is_account_page() && $found  ) {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_checkout_page_id') ) );
    exit();
}
}
```

Comment: This formatting only on this site. On my test site, everything is fine and the formatting is correct.

Comment: Even with the correct formatting, the code `if (is_user_logged_in() &&! WC()->cart->is_empty() && is_account_page ()) {
    wp_redirect (get_permalink (get_option ('woocomm erce_checkout_page_id'))));
}` does not work as it should. That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: I understood. Sorry for this.